# Как задать значение ключевого поля, которое связывает таблицы?

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly

Имеются таблицы игроков и команд, которые связываются через ManyToOne и OneToMany. Конкретный игрок связывается с конкретной командой через поле team_id с id команды, следующим образом.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Team team;
```

При попытке задать данное поле запросом к серверу появляется следующая ошибка

```
Unrecognized field &quot;team_id&quot;
```

Как я понимаю для данного поля нет сеттеров и геттеров, но их не создать тк нет самого поля. Как разрешить данную проблему, а именно как задвать значение полю team_id?

Comment: А что значит задать данное поле запросом к серверу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для задания значения данному полю напрямую необходимо использовать нативный запрос.

```java
entityManager.createNamedQuery("UPDATE player SET team_id = :team_id WHERE id = :player_id")
    .setParameter("team_id", team.getId())
    .setParameter("player_id", player.getId())
    .executeUpdate();
```

Стоит отметить, что теперь будет использоваться SQL, а не JPQL, и обращаться в запросе нужно будет не классу и его полям, а к таблице и ее столбцам.

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня возник следующий вопрос, как правильно заполнять данные таблицы? То есть по хорошему нужно начинать с родительской таблицы и после заполнять ее "детей" (заполняем команду, а потом игроков из этой команды). Просто иначе необходима куча запросов чтоб только просто заполнить две таблицы.

Comment: @AndreySmelik все верно. Создаете команду, делаете ее "постоянной" (persistent) вызовом `entityManager.persist(team)`. Далее создаете игроков, делаете их так же "постоянными" и добавляете в команду. После сброса данных в базу (вызов `entityManager.flush()`) или по завершению транзакции - данные запишутся в базу с проставленной связью.
Если хотите лучше разобрать в устройстве JPA то рекомендую вам почитать книгу "Изучаем Java EE 7" Гонсалвес Э., главы 4-6 (6ая уже непосредственно про entityManager). Лучшего объяснения где-ли бо в интернете чем в этой книге я еще не видел.